# How to make an API call in React on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a marketplace project, I want to show product information and store information like "more products from this store".

Currently my code does the following:

1. Get the product ID from URL and make an API call using that ID to get the product information.
2. State variable `product` is updated with that product information.
3. The product object includes a `storeName` value which I try to use to make another API call to get the store information (more products from that store)

The last step doesn't work. The site loads and the product information is displayed correctly, however the JSON response from the store API call shows an error because the `storeName` value is null. The store information is not displayed.

Code:

```
function ProductPage() {
  const { productUrl } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [store, setStore] = useState([]);

  const {
    name,
    price,
    description,
    images,
    storeName
  } = product;

  useEffect(() => {
    getProduct();
    getStore();
  }, []);

  const getProduct = async () => {
    const product = await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(queries.productByProductId, {
        productId: productUrl,
      })
    );
    setProduct(product.data.productByProductId.items[0]);
  };
  const getStore = async () => {
    const store = await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(queries.storeByName, {
        name: storeName,
      })
    );
    setStore(store.data.storeByName.items[0]);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProduct` and `getStore` are `async operation` and `getStore` is dependent on `getProduct` result other. **Also you must note that state updates depend on the closure and are visible in the next render**. So you need to call `getStore` inside `getProduct`. Also pass in the storeName as argument to `getStore` and do not take it from closure as it will refere to the old value

```
function ProductPage() {
  const { productUrl } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [store, setStore] = useState([]);

  const {
    name,
    price,
    description,
    images,
    storeName
  } = product;

  useEffect(() => {
    getProduct();
  }, []);

  const getProduct = async () => {
    const product = await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(queries.productByProductId, {
        productId: productUrl,
      })
    );
    getStore(product.data.productByProductId.items[0].storeName);
    setProduct(product.data.productByProductId.items[0]);
  };
  const getStore = async (storeName) => {
    const store = await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(queries.storeByName, {
        name: storeName,
      })
    );
    setStore(store.data.storeByName.items[0]);
  };
```

Comment: I just tried your code but keep getting the same error. Have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @LuisGarcia My mistake, You need to call the getStore with correct arguments. `getStore(product.data.productByProductId.items[0].storeName);`. I edited my post. This should work for you and is actually the right way to go instead of adding another useEffect

Answer (score 1):

You can use it , like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    // called as soon as product state updates
    getProduct(); 
}, [product]); // watch for product state update

useEffect(() => {
    // called as soon as store state updates
    getStore();
}, [store]); // watch for store state update
```

> NOTE :
>
> You do not need second `useEffect`, due to *"The product object
>   includes a storeName"* you should call `getStore()` from
>   `getProduct()` as store value depends on product's store as @ShubhamKhatri is explaining, I have missed that point at first glance.

Comment: Clever. Almost _too_ obvious.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner, thanks for appreciation :)

Comment: I love it when an api does things well. It's nice that hooks have this as default functionality. But I'm so used to having to do things the hard way, it's almost shocking that it's so easy.

Comment: Thanks. I tried @ShubhamKhatri code but still get the same error

Comment: What issue you are facing still.? Call  `getStore(product.data.storeName)` from `getProduct()` and use that store name inside `getStore(storeName)`

Comment: Solved it. I just changed `getStore(product.storeName)` to `getStore(product.data.productByProductId.items[0].storeName)`